# ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable - Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I have a problem with my TensorFlow Implementation. When I execute it, I get the above value error. I tried a lot different thinks, but unfortunately I lack of understanding fo the gradients and q_values, so I can't see what might be wrong here. Do you have any ideas, what might be wrong here?

I provide you with: The error message, the full code block, as well as the logging output I've created.

Thank you very much in advance!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TensorFlow.py", line 170, in <module>
    agent.train(state, action, reward, next_state, done)
  File "TensorFlow.py", line 124, in train
    self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.model.trainable_variables))
  File "NextActionPrediction/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/src/optimizers/optimizer.py", line 1229, in apply_gradients
    grads_and_vars = self.aggregate_gradients(grads_and_vars)
  File "NextActionPrediction/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/src/optimizers/optimizer.py", line 1191, in aggregate_gradients
    return optimizer_utils.all_reduce_sum_gradients(grads_and_vars)
  File "NextActionPrediction/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/src/optimizers/utils.py", line 33, in all_reduce_sum_gradients
    filtered_grads_and_vars = filter_empty_gradients(grads_and_vars)
  File "NextActionPrediction/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/src/optimizers/utils.py", line 77, in filter_empty_gradients
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: (['q_network/dense/kernel:0', 'q_network/dense/bias:0', 'q_network/dense_1/kernel:0', 'q_network/dense_1/bias:0', 'q_network/dense_2/kernel:0', 'q_network/dense_2/bias:0'],). Provided `grads_and_vars` is ((None, <tf.Variable 'q_network/dense/kernel:0' shape=(45, 64) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 0.14826034,  0.04778947,  0.19598694, ...,  0.01829259,
        -0.11800514,  0.10064285],
       [ 0.11710103,  0.01960422,  0.04261263, ...,  0.14903928,
         0.15406083,  0.09250544],
       [-0.1903457 ,  0.08159579,  0.00234798, ..., -0.21106957,
        -0.08412273, -0.13572651],
       ...,
       [ 0.12345864, -0.18032698, -0.18760026, ...,  0.0907106 ,
         0.1531611 , -0.13785538],
       [ 0.19176774, -0.04116032, -0.07752809, ..., -0.02622621,
         0.12497725, -0.13471869],
       [ 0.07810323, -0.23371764,  0.20950092, ...,  0.04559319,
         0.13799767, -0.19516735]], dtype=float32)>), (None, <tf.Variable 'q_network/dense/bias:0' shape=(64,) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)>), (None, <tf.Variable 'q_network/dense_1/kernel:0' shape=(64, 64) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[-0.0156869 , -0.03908002, -0.04894392, ...,  0.13892971,
         0.07469149, -0.18481866],
       [ 0.167428  ,  0.01931211,  0.00041626, ..., -0.11669982,
        -0.0033696 , -0.09533404],
       [ 0.03079464,  0.15910648, -0.02356346, ..., -0.02285886,
        -0.19621745,  0.14353181],
       ...,
       [-0.17718954,  0.17343773, -0.01059602, ...,  0.17025273,
         0.07829179,  0.14307953],
       [ 0.12444706, -0.14176674,  0.1480123 , ..., -0.19158922,
        -0.20004769,  0.02778926],
       [ 0.03167093,  0.17244907,  0.21157072, ...,  0.16901381,
         0.09359954, -0.20257805]], dtype=float32)>), (None, <tf.Variable 'q_network/dense_1/bias:0' shape=(64,) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)>), (None, <tf.Variable 'q_network/dense_2/kernel:0' shape=(64, 80) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[-0.1618738 ,  0.01178266, -0.15041229, ..., -0.07665324,
        -0.04814538,  0.04062296],
       [-0.10966177,  0.15106347,  0.13309428, ...,  0.07845193,
        -0.15259233, -0.0842446 ],
       [ 0.15482575, -0.17369503, -0.04180163, ...,  0.15098861,
         0.18587038, -0.03062575],
       ...,
       [-0.09608382,  0.02317259,  0.10707676, ..., -0.11483059,
         0.17886949, -0.09842256],
       [ 0.02895457,  0.16198456,  0.03967786, ...,  0.13098064,
         0.13265035, -0.06779365],
       [ 0.0301746 , -0.10023312, -0.13239358, ..., -0.16881198,
         0.01868351,  0.07911447]], dtype=float32)>), (None, <tf.Variable 'q_network/dense_2/bias:0' shape=(80,) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)>)).
```

My Code, including the logging I tried, looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import gym
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("datasets/featureItems4.csv")
n = len(df)
numFeatures = df.shape[1]
df = df.set_index('timestamp')

trainData = df[0:int(n*0.7)]
valuateData = df[int(n*0.7):int(n*0.9)]
testData = df[int(n*0.9):]

class CustomEnv(gym.Env):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.envdata = pd.DataFrame(data)
        self.current_index = 0
        self.current_state = self.extract_state(self.current_index)
        self.action_space = gym.spaces.Discrete(len(self.envdata))

    def reset(self):
        self.current_index = 0
        self.current_state = self.extract_state(self.current_index)
        return self.current_state

    def step(self, action):
        done = False
        reward = 0.0

        if action == self.current_state[1]:
            reward = 1.0
        else:
            reward = -1.0

        self.current_index += 1
        if self.current_index >= len(self.envdata):
            done = True
            next_state = None
        else:
            next_state = self.extract_state(self.current_index)
            self.current_state = next_state

        return next_state, reward, done, {}

    def extract_state(self, index):
        state_values = self.envdata.iloc[index].values
        unique_values = set()
        state_processed = []

        for val in state_values:
            if isinstance(val, str):
                if val not in unique_values:
                    unique_values.add(val)
                val = float(len(unique_values))
            else:
                val = float(val)
                if np.isnan(val):
                    val = np.nan_to_num(val, nan=0.0)  # Replace NaN with 0.0

            state_processed.append(val)

        return np.array(state_processed, dtype=np.float32)

    def render(self):
        print(self.current_state)

class QNetwork(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, state_size, action_size):
        super(QNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')
        self.fc2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')
        self.fc3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(action_size, activation=None)
        
    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.fc1(inputs)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return self.fc3(x)

# Define the DQN agent
class DQNAgent:
    def __init__(self, state_size, action_size):
        self.state_size = state_size
        self.action_size = action_size
        self.epsilon = 1.0  # Exploration rate
        self.epsilon_decay = 0.99
        self.epsilon_min = 0.01
        self.gamma = 0.99  # Discount factor
        self.learning_rate = 0.001
        self.model = QNetwork(state_size, action_size)
        self.optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=self.learning_rate)
        
    def select_action(self, state):
        if np.random.rand() <= self.epsilon:
            return np.random.choice(self.action_size)
        else:
            q_values = self.model(tf.expand_dims(state, axis=0))
            return tf.argmax(q_values[0]).numpy()
        
    def train(self, state, action, reward, next_state, done):
        q_values = self.model(tf.expand_dims(state, axis=0))
        next_q_values = self.model(tf.expand_dims(next_state, axis=0))
        max_q_value = tf.reduce_max(next_q_values, axis=1)
        target = reward + (1 - tf.cast(done, dtype=tf.float32)) * self.gamma * max_q_value

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            q_value = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(q_values, tf.one_hot(action, self.action_size)), axis=1)
            loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(target - q_value))

        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, self.model.trainable_variables)

        # Log the input and output values of calculations
        print("q_values:", q_values)
        print("next_q_values:", next_q_values)
        print("max_q_value:", max_q_value)
        print("target:", target)
        print("q_value:", q_value)

        # Log the shapes of gradients and trainable variables
        for grad, var in zip(gradients, self.model.trainable_variables):
            print(var.name, "-- gradients:", grad)
            print(var.name, "-- variable shape:", var.shape)

        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.model.trainable_variables))

        if self.epsilon > self.epsilon_min:
            self.epsilon *= self.epsilon_decay

    
    def save_model(self, filename):
        self.model.save_weights(filename)
    
    def load_model(self, filename):
        self.model.load_weights(filename)

# Training and Evaluation
useData = trainData
state_size = numFeatures - 1
num_episodes = 100
env = CustomEnv(useData)
action_size = len(useData['name'].unique().tolist())

print("SETUP Started")
print("state_size: " + str(state_size))
print("action_size: " + str(action_size))
print("useData:")
print(useData.head())
print("")

agent = DQNAgent(state_size, action_size)

# Training loop
print("TRAINING Started")
for episode in range(num_episodes):
    state = env.reset()
    
    print("State: ")
    print(state)
    
    done = False
    
    while not done:
        print("TRAINING Step")
        action = agent.select_action(state)
        print("Action: " + str(action))
        next_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
        print("Reward: " + str(reward))
        print("NextState:")
        print(next_state)
        agent.train(state, action, reward, next_state, done)
        print("Agent trained")
        state = next_state
        
    # Save the model weights every few episodes
    if episode % save_interval == 0:
        agent.save_model('model_weights.h5')

# Evaluation
agent.load_model('model_weights.h5')
state = env.reset()
done = False

while not done:
    action = agent.select_action(state)
    next_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
    state = next_state
```

And the logging output looks like this:

```
2023-07-15 10:25:13.766229: I tensorflow/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:28] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
2023-07-15 10:25:13.827783: I tensorflow/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:28] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
2023-07-15 10:25:13.828368: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-07-15 10:25:14.619000: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
SETUP Started
state_size: 45
action_size: 80
useData:
                              name  type          package                                               data    daySin    dayCos   weekSin  ...  boot  scrOff scrOn  shutdown  present  headset  headsetPlugged
timestamp                                                                                                                                   ...                                                                
1688247116627  3599524920675246655     3  P:com.miui.home  ["C:android.widget.ImageView", "CD:3Bildschirm...  0.913161  0.407600 -0.669231  ...     0       0     0         0        0        0               0
1688247116843  6376691910461194777     3  P:com.miui.home  ["C:android.widget.ImageView", "CD:2Bildschirm...  0.919450  0.393207 -0.667562  ...     0       0     0         0        0        0               0
1688247117060  3599524920675246655     3  P:com.miui.home  ["C:android.widget.ImageView", "CD:3Bildschirm...  0.925541  0.378649 -0.665882  ...     0       0     0         0        0        0               0
1688247117243  6376691910461194777     3  P:com.miui.home  ["C:android.widget.ImageView", "CD:2Bildschirm...  0.930498  0.366298 -0.664462  ...     0       0     0         0        0        0               0
1688247117477  3599524920675246655     3  P:com.miui.home  ["C:android.widget.ImageView", "CD:3Bildschirm...  0.936596  0.350412 -0.662643  ...     0       0     0         0        0        0               0

[5 rows x 45 columns]

TRAINING Started
State: 
[ 3.5995248e+18  3.0000000e+00  1.0000000e+00  2.0000000e+00
  9.1316098e-01  4.0759999e-01 -6.6923100e-01  7.4305397e-01
  2.8400000e+02  3.0000000e+00  4.8000000e+01  2.7355400e+05
  2.0000000e+01  5.6640002e+02  1.3553801e+00  4.0000000e+00
  6.6000003e-01  0.0000000e+00  5.0000000e+00  6.0000000e+00
  6.0000000e+00  6.3766919e+18  3.5995248e+18  6.3766919e+18
  3.5995248e+18  6.3766919e+18  2.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00
  0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00  7.0000000e+00
  0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00
  0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00
  0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00
  0.0000000e+00]
TRAINING Step
Action: 37
Reward: -1.0
NextState:
[ 6.3766919e+18  3.0000000e+00  1.0000000e+00  2.0000000e+00
  9.1944999e-01  3.9320701e-01 -6.6756201e-01  7.4455398e-01
  5.0000000e+02  3.0000000e+00  4.8000000e+01  2.7355400e+05
  2.0000000e+01  5.6640002e+02  1.3553801e+00  4.0000000e+00
  6.6000003e-01  0.0000000e+00  5.0000000e+00  6.0000000e+00
  6.0000000e+00  3.5995248e+18  6.3766919e+18  3.5995248e+18
  6.3766919e+18  3.5995248e+18  2.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00
  0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00  7.0000000e+00
  0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00
  0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00
  0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00
  0.0000000e+00]
q_values: tf.Tensor(
[[-5.25375930e+17 -1.65881807e+18  2.34805261e+17 -3.88067681e+17
  -1.31917275e+18 -1.33992576e+18 -2.25640127e+17  7.74072404e+17
   8.30835396e+16 -1.48748846e+18 -3.03379447e+17  4.89582704e+17
   9.66041499e+17  3.73420434e+17 -1.72956271e+17 -2.96892020e+17
  -5.12931589e+17  5.05499990e+17 -4.78794227e+17  6.50339567e+16
   2.57052745e+17  6.43533023e+17  1.11182581e+18  1.42025171e+17
  -1.20569600e+18  8.24809505e+17 -6.38012994e+17 -2.30616709e+18
   2.15807212e+17  4.68882301e+17  3.32898792e+17 -6.51937005e+15
   4.75943743e+17 -2.29083797e+18  1.77521169e+17  6.13765601e+17
  -4.98325333e+17 -9.95788649e+17 -2.74743749e+17  1.16673398e+18
   1.00583557e+18  1.87898978e+18  4.80027123e+17  9.95549642e+17
  -1.40113708e+18 -3.76714055e+17  1.73286365e+17  4.13236945e+17
  -4.15549871e+17 -2.56424226e+18  2.43438712e+17 -5.24724848e+17
  -1.85517697e+18  9.38618786e+17 -5.95651628e+17  2.13848569e+17
  -2.81749906e+17  7.10117910e+16 -8.08393865e+17  3.95082746e+16
  -4.25301337e+17 -3.34909593e+17 -3.46722849e+17  1.21145730e+18
  -1.34578385e+17 -4.38194726e+17  2.66326249e+17 -1.23807497e+18
   9.74376072e+17  1.03676374e+18  3.69061798e+17 -1.66183417e+17
  -2.45452055e+17 -6.06758070e+17  8.30489033e+17  9.49067513e+17
   7.98334021e+17 -5.39190916e+17  2.59258726e+17 -5.52327683e+16]], shape=(1, 80), dtype=float32)
next_q_values: tf.Tensor(
[[-8.24572011e+17 -1.96836427e+18  2.94831569e+17 -5.96039137e+17
  -9.22041930e+17 -1.56764094e+18  2.27656786e+17  8.28646663e+17
   1.37042975e+17 -6.00480546e+17 -2.93733501e+17  5.01755053e+17
   1.57784372e+18 -4.36071912e+17 -1.18199330e+17 -8.20932146e+17
  -6.70985286e+17  3.28272631e+17 -5.19262955e+17  4.34377702e+16
   4.51597738e+17 -1.22810230e+16  1.83154517e+17 -2.11428080e+17
  -6.99732773e+17  3.34981473e+17 -1.02962206e+18 -2.22328219e+18
   3.34959277e+17  2.27180045e+17  2.98798882e+17  3.13224131e+17
   3.47305177e+17 -2.30428074e+18 -1.69939143e+17  6.29448348e+17
   3.74288052e+17 -9.02489589e+17 -6.83209862e+17  1.30199893e+18
   9.42257826e+17  9.91890330e+17  5.89898640e+17  1.13097731e+18
  -8.26746707e+17  3.11954367e+17  3.86569820e+16  5.46891655e+17
  -7.98880891e+17 -2.14978754e+18  4.45148724e+17 -1.07343680e+17
  -1.45061304e+18 -1.15838360e+17 -5.42432585e+17  7.40992978e+17
  -1.28638523e+17  4.28815720e+17 -1.31176522e+17 -3.96062814e+16
  -1.70747816e+17  5.46468480e+17 -3.18600468e+17  1.46048418e+18
  -5.78703893e+17 -5.10456451e+17 -2.50115771e+17 -1.95547181e+18
   1.00671085e+18  9.84323285e+17  6.72420355e+17  1.16605553e+17
  -2.21812624e+17 -3.91968474e+17  4.00209176e+17  3.23890768e+17
   6.89828510e+17 -4.32811139e+17  4.91725068e+17  1.76379292e+17]], shape=(1, 80), dtype=float32)
max_q_value: tf.Tensor([1.5778437e+18], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
target: tf.Tensor([1.5620653e+18], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
q_value: tf.Tensor([-9.9578865e+17], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
q_network/dense/kernel:0 -- gradients: None
q_network/dense/kernel:0 -- variable shape: (45, 64)
q_network/dense/bias:0 -- gradients: None
q_network/dense/bias:0 -- variable shape: (64,)
q_network/dense_1/kernel:0 -- gradients: None
q_network/dense_1/kernel:0 -- variable shape: (64, 64)
q_network/dense_1/bias:0 -- gradients: None
q_network/dense_1/bias:0 -- variable shape: (64,)
q_network/dense_2/kernel:0 -- gradients: None
q_network/dense_2/kernel:0 -- variable shape: (64, 80)
q_network/dense_2/bias:0 -- gradients: None
q_network/dense_2/bias:0 -- variable shape: (80,)
```

As I lack of understanding here, I tried different conversions of the input data, but the only thing that happened was, that sometimes I got an error earlier...

Comment: You need to compute the forward pass and all related values inside the gradient tape, inside the with statement.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Dr.Snoopy in the comments, the issue with my code was wrong indentation in the train function, which led to the fact, that statements were not called in the full context of tape.

The corrected, and now working function therefore looks like this:

```
ef train(self, state, action, reward, next_state, done):
    q_values = self.model(tf.expand_dims(state, axis=0))
    next_q_values = self.model(tf.expand_dims(next_state, axis=0))
    max_q_value = tf.reduce_max(next_q_values, axis=1)
    target = reward + (1 - tf.cast(done, dtype=tf.float32)) * self.gamma * max_q_value

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        q_values = self.model(tf.expand_dims(state, axis=0))
        next_q_values = self.model(tf.expand_dims(next_state, axis=0))
        max_q_value = tf.reduce_max(next_q_values, axis=1)
        target = reward + (1 - tf.cast(done, dtype=tf.float32)) * self.gamma * max_q_value

        q_value = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(q_values, tf.one_hot(action, self.action_size)), axis=1)
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(target - q_value))

        trainable_vars = self.model.trainable_variables
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)

    self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.model.trainable_variables))

    if self.epsilon > self.epsilon_min:
        self.epsilon *= self.epsilon_decay
```

This ensures that the tape can trace the operations and compute the gradients correctly.

If you self encounter this error, you can find out that there is something wrong with the **Computation** of the gradients (in comparison with errors in the loss function), when the loss computations are correctly, i.e.:

```
# Add this code after the loss computation
# Get the trainable variables
trainable_vars = self.model.trainable_variables

# Check if the loss depends on the trainable variables
for var in trainable_vars:
    if tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(loss * tf.stop_gradient(var))) != 0:
        print("Loss depends on variable:", var.name)
    else:
        print("Loss does not depend on variable:", var.name)
```

outputs something like

```
Loss depends on variable: q_network/dense/kernel:0
Loss does not depend on variable: q_network/dense/bias:0
Loss depends on variable: q_network/dense_1/kernel:0
Loss does not depend on variable: q_network/dense_1/bias:0
Loss depends on variable: q_network/dense_2/kernel:0
Loss does not depend on variable: q_network/dense_2/bias:0
```

But the gradients before the apply_gradients, i.e. calculated like this:

```
# Check the gradients
for grad, var in zip(gradients, self.model.trainable_variables):
    if grad is None:
        print(f"No gradient provided for variable: {var.name}")
    else:
        print(f"Gradient exists for variable: {var.name}")

# Apply gradients and update the model
self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.model.trainable_variables))
```

output this:

```
No gradient provided for variable: q_network/dense/kernel:0
No gradient provided for variable: q_network/dense/bias:0
No gradient provided for variable: q_network/dense_1/kernel:0
No gradient provided for variable: q_network/dense_1/bias:0
No gradient provided for variable: q_network/dense_2/kernel:0
No gradient provided for variable: q_network/dense_2/bias:0
```

Very much thanks to @Dr.Snoopy to giving me the hint for understanding the outputs I got, and for solving my problem. I hope the above will help other people, that also encounter this ValueError to further trace down the cause.